# systemd bridge for VM + multiple static IPs

Tags: routing, ip, linux-networking, kvm-virtualization, systemd

I have a Ubuntu 18.04 server with 3 public IPs. The main IP is already preconfigured.

I would like to configure IP2 and IP3. IP2 is to be used for a SSL domain and IP3 for a virtual machine (qemu libvirt).
The problem (for me) is, that previous versions of Ubuntu used upstart and I was able to configure it, but the 
current version has systemd and I can't sort it out.

Previously I used the following howto for configration and everything worked fine:
https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Netzkonfiguration_Debian/en#Routed_.28brouter.29

Now, with systemd, this is the network configuration file (only with 1 IP) which I started out with:

```
# /etc/systemd/network/10-eno1.network
[Match] 
Name=eno1 

[Network]
Gateway=IP_GATEWAY

[Address] 
Address=IP1
Peer=IP_GATEWAY/32
```

Adding IP2 (for SSL) is easy as it just requires an additional [Address] section in the file above.

As for IP3, I guess that in order to route IP3 to my VM, I need to create a bridge as in the original howto.
So when trying to configure a qemu/libvirt bridge for the VM I ended up with something very similar to this configuration:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=193994
i.e. - br0 device + eno1 added to bridge + configure bridge like above

But just like in the above thread the server becomes unreachable (can't ping in/out) and the output of the 
diagnostic commands is pretty much the same.

Any suggestions on how to configure IP3 for use with VM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to find the solution myself. 
It took me much too long because when I tested it in a virtual KVM it didn't work for some reason.

Assume that:

- IP1 - my server's primary IP
- IP2 - extra IP used for my website's SSL certificate
- IP3 - extra IP used for my virtual machine
- eno1 is my physical ethernet interface

On the host - 3 files:

```
# /etc/systemd/network/10-virbr1.netdev
[NetDev]
Name=virbr1
Kind=bridge
MACAddress=00:1e:67:ad:8d:12

[Bridge]
STP=false

# /etc/systemd/network/20-eno1.network
[Match]
Name=eno1

[Network]
Bridge=virbr1

# /etc/systemd/network/30-virbr1.network
[Match]
Name=virbr1

[Network]
Gateway=IP_GATEWAY

[Address]
Address=IP1
Peer=IP_GATEWAY/32

[Address]
Address=IP2
Peer=IP_GATEWAY/32
```

On the virtual machine (some older Ubuntu - doesn't use systemd):

```
# /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address IP3
    netmask 255.255.255.255
    gateway IP_GATEWAY
    pointopoint IP_GATEWAY
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1
```

Some extra explanation:
MACAddress=00:1e:67:ad:8d:12 was necessary because my hosting company (Hetzner) does some MAC filtering so the bridge has to have the MAC of the physical ethernet card.

For the same reason the VM needs to have some specific MAC address which you can generate in Hetzner's server control panel. So in my case the output of "virsh dumpxml my-vm" looks like this:

```
...
<interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='00:50:56:00:53:E1'/>
      <source bridge='virbr1'/>
      <target dev='vnet0'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <alias name='net0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
...
```

Comment: Hey, @wanson, thank you very much for sharing your solution!